# mySQL inner join with HOUR(CONVERT_TZ

Tags: mysql, join, alias

I am trying to execute the SQL below, but I am getting the error: Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 't.tid' in 'on clause'

Can anyone help me get it working?

```
SELECT SUM(amount) AS A, HOUR(CONVERT_TZ(timeframe, 'UTC', '+3:00')) AS tid FROM transactions AS t 
left join hours AS h on t.tid=h.hours
GROUP BY HOUR(CONVERT_TZ(timeframe, 'UTC', '+3:00'))
order by HOUR(CONVERT_TZ(timeframe, 'UTC', '+3:00'));
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message is loud and clear `Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 't.tid' in 'on clause'.` 
You cannot use your `ALIAS` in your `WHERE` clause directly like that:

try

```
SELECT SUM(amount) AS A, HOUR(CONVERT_TZ(timeframe, 'UTC', '+3:00')) AS tid FROM transactions AS t 
left join hours AS h on HOUR(CONVERT_TZ(timeframe, 'UTC', '+3:00'))=h.hours
GROUP BY HOUR(CONVERT_TZ(timeframe, 'UTC', '+3:00'))
order by HOUR(CONVERT_TZ(timeframe, 'UTC', '+3:00'))
```